# MySql Syntax error when creating trigger to insert calculated value

Tags: mysql, triggers

This is my first time trying to create a MySql trigger but I'm running into syntax errors that I can't identify. I am trying to have the trigger insert a calculated value when a row is updated. Below is my code, but I keep getting syntax errors when I try to execute it, and I cannot see where the error is. Can someone please look, what am I doing wrong?

```
DROP TRIGGER ins_cop_dhw;
CREATE TRIGGER ins_cop_dhw BEFORE INSERT ON `2017010001_data`
   FOR EACH ROW 
   BEGIN
       IF (NEW.`_007E` = 1 AND `_00A2` > 0) THEN
           SET NEW.`_00B7` = NEW.`_0096` / NEW.`_00A2`;
       END IF;
       IF (NEW.`_007D` = 1 AND `_00A2` > 0) THEN
           SET NEW.`_00B8` = (NEW.`_0096` / NEW.`_00A2`);
       END IF;
   END;
```

Here is the error I get in MySQL Workbench, but it's not much help. :/

```
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual 
that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to 
use near '' at line 5
```

MySQL Workbench highlights the end of line 6 as the start of the syntax error.
[image: Screenshot of MySql Workbench syntax error highlighting]

Comment: Well, this is like the third question today (I think) where I tell people to post the error message they're receiving.

Comment: Looks like DELIMITER command lost.

Comment: @FaNo_FN you're right, I've edited the question to include the error.

Comment: @Akina what do you mean? I don't understand.

Comment: Study [CREATE PROCEDURE and CREATE FUNCTION Statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html), especially code examples and the text after 1st code block, and [Defining Stored Programs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html). Also read Workbench' Help about this point.

Answer (score 0):

As said by @Akina I was missing the `delimiter` statements. Here is fixed code.

```
delimiter //
DROP TRIGGER ins_cop_dhw;
CREATE TRIGGER ins_cop_dhw BEFORE INSERT ON `2017010001_data`
   FOR EACH ROW 
   BEGIN
       IF (NEW.`_007E` = 1 AND NEW.`_00A2` > 0) THEN
           SET NEW.`_00B7` = NEW.`_0096` / NEW.`_00A2`;
       END IF;
       IF (NEW.`_007D` = 1 AND NEW.`_00A2` > 0) THEN
           SET NEW.`_00B8` = (NEW.`_0096` / NEW.`_00A2`);
       END IF;
   END//
   delimiter ;
```

As per the advice of @Akina I read the [Create Procedure](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html) documentation from the dev.mysql.com site and the below quote highlighted the importance of using `delimiter`

> The example uses the mysql client delimiter command to change the statement delimiter from ; to // while the procedure is being defined. This enables the ; delimiter used in the procedure body to be passed through to the server rather than being interpreted by mysql itself. See Section 25.1, “Defining Stored Programs”.